# What famous word or phrase can I use to tell people my surname is 袁?

Tags: traditional-characters, conversation, colloquialisms

I know in Chinese people sometimes use other common words or phrases to tell people what characters their Chinese name has.

My Chinese name is Yuan Li Heng (袁禮恒)

For Li I can say Li Wu 禮物 and for Heng I can say Yong Heng 永恒. Yuan is a little harder because from I've heard, it's more just a common surname.

What's usually the best way to tell people what character it is in Chinese if the character itself doesn't really have any associated meanings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just mention a famous person with that surname, e.g.

- [袁紹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_Shao) from the Three Kingdoms
- [袁崇煥](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_Chonghuan), patriot, martyr, and brilliant military commander who was instrumental in repelling the Jurchens for the Ming Dynasty
- [袁世凱](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuan_Shikai), first president of the Republic of China

Answer (score 3):

Referencing famous names is a good idea. But if it still doesn't work, you might have to describe the radicals.

For example, my surname is 张. I was often asked to clarify whether it's 立-早 章 or 弓-长 张, when I told them my surname pronounced as 'zhang'.

Comment: Ooo can you actually dive more into this? What would be an appropriate way to do that? I actually try to use 遠 and I want to say without that horse radical. What would be the appropriate way to do that?

Comment: @aug What dan means is to break down the character into components, e.g. 袁 would be broken down into 土口, but  is not a character so you'd describe it as e.g. "the bottom part of 衣". Btw, the left hand component of 遠 is 辵 or ⻍, not *horse*.

Comment: @aug, as long as you can get that clear to your interlocutor. The way you interpret 袁(*I actually try to use 遠 and I want to say without that horse radical*) is fine. And droooze's is fine too.

Comment: @aug In your method I hope you're clear about the audience you're talking to, because trying to break down 遠 to simplified Chinese users won't work very well, since 遠 is written 远 in simplified Chinese, and they might misinterpret your surname as 元, which is a valid surname.

Comment: Ah sorry my radicals aren't very good >< thanks for correcting @drooze. And thanks for the info @dan!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This visual represents the nationwide distribution of the Yuan (袁) surname, and was created by genetics researcher Yuan Yida (袁义达).

If you're looking for a visual, this one is quite relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the answer:

We generally tend to choose celebrities with a relatively positive image, if possible. The extent of this is very subtle. For example, 袁世凱 is very famous but he has a bad reputation. 袁咏仪, an Chinese actor, is a safer option than him. 袁隆平, almost a saint in the hearts of Chinese people, everyone will know which 袁 you are talking about, But out of respect, if it were me, I wouldn't use him to introduce the surname.